# WCF SSL .pfx Binding

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, ssl, https

My API call another secure API internally below is my code :

```
string ID = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ID"]);
string Password = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);
string client_ID = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["client_ID"]);
string client_secret = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["client_secret"]);
string patchURI = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecureApi"]);
patchURI = patchURI + "?client_ID=" + client_ID + "&client_secret=" + client_secret;

string JsonStringParams = jsonStringRequest();

//ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonStringParams);
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(patchURI);
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";


request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Headers.Add("UserName", LDAPID);
request.Headers.Add("Password", Password);
string requestData = JsonStringParams;
data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
dataStream.Close();
var response = request.GetResponse(); // failed at this stage Error : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.",
string result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

my patchURI contains a https link which needs a .pfx SSL and client has already same .cer/crt installed
When i use the patchURI and pass SSL in SOAPUI Tool i get response from Client server, but when i use through this code it fails and generates and err : - Failed to Create SSL Channel.

Comment: It is a red flag that "has already same .cer/crt installed". Unless you are using full purposed testing certificates, the server and the client must each have its own certificate with the right purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The error typically indicates that the trust relationship has not been established yet. In order to establish the relationship between the client-side and the server-side, we should install each other’s certificate in the `TRUSTED ROOT CERTIFICATION AUTHORITIES` store.
It is not recommended to call the WCF service by using an `Http` client library except that the WCF service created by `WebHttpbinding`(`Restful WCF` service).  We usually call the WCF soap web service by using a client proxy. The below code can be used for manually verifying the certificate while sending an Http request.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate
{
    return true;
};
```

Besides, please post the complete error message if the error still exists.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.